# Netsuite - Track Mass Deleted Records

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I want to get details about deleted records from inline-editing. Taken logs of all the fields for the same. An aftersubmit user-event script works for this where,

```
if(context.type == context.UserEventType.DELETE) the context type is delete.
```

When I go to that record, click edit and then in the Actions menu click delete, then logs are printed. But this thing is not happening when deleted from inline-editing mode.
Do I have to do this in XEDIT mode? Is there any other solution? please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use XEDIT , Use DELETE and Try with User Event before submit , as after submit will error out to record not found

Comment: Thanks. But in beforeSubmit, we dont know the record is deleted or not right?

Comment: beforeSubmit will give you the loaded transaction details which you load through - 
var load = record.load(recordType,recordId);
var value = load.getValue('fieldId');
and / or its field values , even if record gets deleted you can load the record object and retrieve field values as the record is not yet committed to the server ( database ) .

Comment: Right. Using load record I am getting all info in beforeSubmit and creating a custom record to store all the values. But if we delete Sales Order and it has dependent rec, it will not allow us to delete it. but the custom record will get created in background. So, how can we handle this?

Comment: you can deploy the script on sales order and delete the dependent / child record of that sales order from ui as i have tested similarly